# Hidden Schema permissions

Tags: sql-server

It was requested to create user with the same permissions as example user.
I had investigated example user and provide the same permissions as example had.
Customer confirmed that new user has proper permissions : Read for 1 schema and rewdwrite for other. But I have n't provided read- write for second schema!
It's domain users with a lot of groups and some of them has login in DB...
I couldn't find who provided read-write.
It looks read-write is assigned for the schema on the whole (see picture) and I can suppose it's from some domain group(?) ...
[image: picture from GUI for the schema where investigated table is located]

To find grantor I decided to take 1 table from the schema and investigated with s_help*** , database_permissions and fn_my_permissions.Also I have reviewed (sp_helplogins)  user groups from  xp_logininfo and couldn't find any interesting.
[image: picture with sqlcmd input-output]

Comment: What is your question?...you want to know *who* granted the permissions on this schema?

Comment: YES
I want to know who granted the permitions on the schema